# Vaadin and JPARepository: transaction errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, spring-data-jpa, vaadin7

I'm having troubles in integrating Vaadin and spring-data (JPARepositories in particular).

After following the guidance of Vaadin's team with their last webinar I managed to configure my application using Spring starter (spring boot), adding Vaadin, JPA and a Postgresql database. Using this method was really straightforward and loading entities to a table works out of the box by simply having this

```
@Autowired private ProjectDAO projects;

// other code here ...
grid.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<Project>(Project.class, projects.findAll()));
```

My repository is just

```
@Repository
public class ProjectDAO implements JPARepository<Project, Long> {

}
```

And, as I said, this works flawlessly. The problem is when I try to save something: when trying to save a project via a button click, for example

```
btnSave.addClickListener(e -> saveCurrent());

private void saveCurrent() {
// ... here I do some filesystem operations, nothing that requires DB connection
    setModified();
}

public void setModified() {
    project.setLastAccess(new Date());
    projects.saveAndFlush(project);
}
```

I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress.
```

I've tried many different things, such as marking the `setModified` method as `@Transactional`, or encapsulating the `setModified` into a service class, but everything always throws this exception.

I find it rather strange that this doesn't work "out of the box", and I'd rather not work with transactions myself, since there are already the instruments to do that.

Any help would be really appreciated

**EDIT 12/05/2015**

It seems that this problem only appears when using an external server, not the embedded one provided by spring-boot. For test purposes I can manage to use the built-in, but eventually I will have to deploy the application on an existing server, so what could the issue be? Tomcat's configuration?

Comment: Spring @Transactional works only if the method marked with it is in a bean that is created from the SpringContext...otherwise there is a technique called [Open Session In View](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html), it's not the best scalable solution, but it works and is very easy to use.

Comment: This explains why `@Transactional` doesn't work in the `@SpringView` view of Vaadin, but then I also put the same annotation within a `@Service` class and the exception is still thrown. Shouldn't the `@Service` be created from the SpringContext once I use the `@Autowired`?

Comment: Yes, you need also to have the transaction enabled in your application, check the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations), but there are two way with a tag if you are using the spring xml configuration, or with an annotation if you are using annotation based configuration

Comment: Yes, I looked at that documentation before, and I used the `@EnableTransactionManagement` in the `@Configuration` annotated class that gives the configuration of the web application, that is what bothers me, nothing seems to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs the answer I'll leave here what I found out after a few days of breaking my head on it.

Before deploying the application I changed some configurations on the main class that was generated by Spring Initializr (The application one) and made it extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` because I was following the guide I found in [the official spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications). Turns out that this was in fact not necessary because I set up "WAR" in Spring Initializr from the beginning, thus the application already had a class extending that one, and as a result when deploying it on Tomcat, the web application started twice, so the application was configured twice and two persistence units were instantiated. This probably was the error, because after reverting the changes I made to the application everything worked fine.

TL;DR: if you use Spring Initializr to create a WAR application don't touch anything.